# MySQL table default charset and changing it if needed. Is it safe to change it?

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8, character-encoding, latin1

I have a database and when I do `show create table actual_table` I see in the output:
`ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`

`Latin1` is `ISO8859-1`, right? So does this mean that if I access the DB via e.g. a script that encodes in `UTF-8` the result in the database could be garbage?
So if this is the case, should I convert the table's encoding to `UTF-8`? Is the conversion safe?